# PHP PDO Delete a Value and Values from an Array

Tags: php, pdo

How can I remove multiple values (in an array) from MySQL Database?
I have a string with User-ID and an array of Article_IDs.

```
$user_id = 1;
$article_id = [1,2,3,4];

$deleteValues = "DELETE FROM my_table WHERE user_id = ? AND id = ?";
$delt = $db->prepare($deleteValues);
$delt->bindParam(1, $user_id);
$delt->bindParam(2, $article_id);
$delt->execute();
```

I have different users and articles in the Database. I need activated Prepare Statements. My Example doesn't work.Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked that the parameter values actually match what you're expecting them to? And have you set/opened a connection properly?

Comment: Can you display the database and the public function you're running that code in?

Comment: just to give you a hint, try to print the value of `$deleteValues` and then run the result directly in you MySQL console.

Comment: You are trying to concatenate a string with an array when passing $article_id (an array) as parameter to that query.
Try updating the query to `DELETE FROM my_table WHERE user_id = ? AND id IN(?)`

Comment: Use the `IN` syntax `AND id IN ()`

Comment: I get Notice: Array to string conversion in

Comment: It works!
$deleteValues = "DELETE FROM my_table WHERE user_id = ? AND id IN (" . implode(",", $articeValues) . ")";
$delt = $db->prepare($deleteValues);
$delt->bindParam(1, $user_id);
$delt->execute();